# Getting average of "time" data type column - Clarification

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I was trying to get the average of a column (called length_of_ride) which had a datatype of time.
From my understanding, you can’t actually do this because in Big Query, the "time" data type cannot be averaged. Error is as follows.

> No matching signature for aggregate function AVG for argument types: TIME. Supported signatures: AVG(INT64); AVG(FLOAT64); AVG(NUMERIC); AVG(BIGNUMERIC); AVG(INTERVAL) at [2:4]

Received a solution that is similar to following code, however I’m not fully certain why it works.

```
SELECT
   AVG(length_of_ride - '0:0:0') as length_of_ride_1,
```

From my understanding, it seems to be changing the data type of the "length_of_ride" column to an interval data type. This can then be averaged as per error screenshot previously posted.
However I'm not fully sure that this is the case and would like confirmation to be safe.
Could someone please verify if my previous assumption is correct? If it's not could someone then please explain what the logic behind the code is?

Edit: Removed screenshot of error as requested in comments section and replaced as quote.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Try convert time to seconds using DATEPART function.

`SELECT  AVG(DATEPART(SECOND, length_of_ride - '0:0:0'))`